# I want to extend React-Query support on old browsers without manually testing my Next application on the said old browsers

Tags: next.js, react-query, browser-support, swc-compiler

I found this quote on the installation page but I don't understand the approach they want me to take:

> "Depending on your environment, you might need to add polyfills. If you want to support older browsers, you need to transpile the library from node_modules yourselves."

You can check it [here](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/installation#:%7E:text=Depending%20on%20your%20environment%2C%20you%20might%20need%20to%20add%20polyfills.%20If%20you%20want%20to%20support%20older%20browsers%2C%20you%20need%20to%20transpile%20the%20library%20from%20node_modules%20yourselves.)

I compared the default suppoted browers listed [here](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/installation#requirements) vs. the release dates of those versions and would like to extend my application's support for browsers, ideally 5 and upto 10 years old.

Default React query browser support:

```
Chrome >= 73
Firefox >= 78
Edge >= 79
Safari >= 12.0
iOS >= 12.0
opera >= 53
```

I am currently using

- TanStack Query v4
- Next.js v13 (SWC)

So far I have tried following the SWC documentation for browser support: [docs](https://swc.rs/docs/configuration/supported-browsers)

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue but with different versions :

- TanStack Query v5
- Next.js v14 (SWC)

you can use this config in `next.config.js` :

```
transpilePackages: ['@tanstack/query-core', ...any other package that is breaking on old browsers]
```

this will transpile and bundle the dependencies you provide from local packages according to [Nextjs documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/transpilePackages)

Hope it helps!